# Did any theatre get all endings to Clue?

Tags: distribution, clue

The 1985 film *Clue* famously has three different endings, with different theatres getting a different ending.

Were there any theatres that got all three endings? Or that set out to acquire all three?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure many of them did.  The one near me played different endings on different nights.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted an answer based on my personal experience?